# How do i block my website from loading on mobiles?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

For example when someone visit my website he see a page for downloading an app

Comment: How about just not doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3514784/6227513 this is your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.platform` to get the platform of the browser. According to it open different pages.